# how to solve The network path was not found in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to run my MVC application through visual studio but unfortunately, I am getting the network path was not found please find stack trace below

```
System.IO.IOException occurred
  HResult=0x00000035
  Message=The network path was not found.

  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32ErrorStatic(Int32 errorCode, String str)
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive hKey, String machineName, RegistryView view)
   at MV.SharedServices.EventLoggingUtilities.GenericUtilities.writeEventThread()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

in web.config

```
   <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="MV.SharedServices.EventLoggingUtilities" publicKeyToken="7A367428B8A3AE49" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

I know that something wrong with registry editor settings but I don't know exactly what to do

Comment: We can't help you without being able to see your code.  What is `MV.SharedServices.EventLoggingUtilities.GenericUtilities.writeEventThread`?

Comment: whatever file / location you are trying to access ... "is not found". Use debugger to see which path throws the exception

Comment: @Amy MV.SharedServices.EventLoggingUtilities is a dll which i am referring in my application

Comment: @ravi I was asking for your code.  We cannot help you if we cannot see your code.

Comment: The assembly binding element from your web.config is not code, nor is it helpful.

Comment: @ravi Do you have the source code for `MV.SharedServices.EventLoggingUtilities.GenericUtilities.writeEventThread`?  That is the *only* non-Framework method in your stack trace, so the problem is in the code there.  Do you have it or not?

Comment: @Amy that is the only place i found about MV.SharedServices.EventLoggingUtilities in my application

Comment: no, I don't have

Comment: If you can't provide us the code, not sure how you think we'll be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

> at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32ErrorStatic(Int32 errorCode, String str)
>
> at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive hKey, String machineName, RegistryView view)

These error indicates you are trying to read the registry of a remote computer?  Did you pass in the name of computer on the network.

Either way to the computer doesn't not exist.